# htaccess rewrite does not work in some pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**.htaccess file:**

I have the following htaccess file (it's very short):

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&params=$2 [L]
```

I think is easy to understand it: if a file doesn't exists, then the url is rewrited.

**The problem:**

An "error" folder or file doesn't exists so it should be rewrited. However, when I try to access to `url.local/error/404` don't works, but `url.local/error` works.

Maybe a problem with Apache?

**Edit:**

Summary:

- `http://url.local/dir` works
- `http://url.local/dir/subdir` works
- `http://url.local/dir/subdir/subdir` works
- `http://url.local/error` works
- `http://url.local/error/subdir` **don't works**

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe a problem with Apache?

No there is no Apache problem. Issue is that your regex is not matching `/` but your input has one.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&params=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct but still doesn't works, same apache 404 error. It's very strange because `url.local/error` works but `url.local/error/400` not

Comment: By the way, I'm using a virtual host in my laptop (see I'm writing `url.local`), but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Exact same URL with same rules works fine on my Apache. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Yep, 500 error. I didn't delete the garbage, try to access to `url.local/error/xxx` and surprise: 404 error.

Comment: Yep, in `error/` I get a 500 error but in `error/xxx` I get a 404, and it doesn't exists `error/` subdirectory. It's hilarious

Comment: Yes, I get the 404 error when I write `error/xxx` ("xxx" could be anything). My htaccess file is a copy/paste of your answer

Comment: Summary:
`/asdf` works,
`/asdf/asdf` works,
`/error` works,
`/error/asdf` don't works

Comment: That could be due to some setting in your Apache config because there is nothing specific to `/error/<anything>` in above rules. Moreover with these rules `/error/xxx` also works on my Apache.

Comment: I will keep searching. If I find the solution I'll post it